# how many device loged in in the same time with same user&pass [flutter]

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

i have a paid app my database is MYSQL, i wanna know how many devices is logeed in in the same time with the same USER & PASS

any idea?

Comment: The number of users that can be signed in with the same username and password is not limited. That is not handled by the database itself, you will have to do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the device id, platform, os version and other almost unique device's information in the database when the user logins. After that you can distinguish how many devices are logged with same login and password.

P.s. do not forget remove save devices data from database when user log out